# Set optional disabled attribute

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to disable all fields in my form, which have values when page is loaded.
For example in this

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PracticeName, new { style = "width:100%", disabled = Model.PracticeName == String.Empty ? "Something Here" : "disabled" })</td>
```

I want to write inline something like this. I don't want to use if-else and make my code larger.
Using javascript/jquery doesn't welcome too.

I tried to write false/true, but 1.It maybe isn't cross-browser 2.Mvc parsed it to string like "True" and "False".
So how can I do it?

P.S. I use ASP.NET MVC 3 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a good candidate for a custom helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex,
        object htmlAttributes,
        bool disabled
    )
    {
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        if (disabled)
        {
            attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
        }
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(ex, attributes);
    }
}
```

which could be used like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    m => m.PracticeName, 
    new { style = "width:100%" }, 
    Model.PracticeName != String.Empty
)
```

The helper could obviously be taken a step further so that you don't need to pass an additional boolean value but it automatically determines whether the value of the expression is equal to `default(TProperty)` and it applies the `disabled` attribute.

Another possibility is an extension method like this:

```
public static class AttributesExtensions
{
    public static RouteValueDictionary DisabledIf(
        this object htmlAttributes, 
        bool disabled
    )
    {
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        if (disabled)
        {
            attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
        }
        return attributes;
    }
}
```

which you would use with the standard `TextBoxFor` helper:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    m => m.PracticeName, 
    new { style = "width:100%" }.DisabledIf(Model.PracticeName != string.Empty)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used second extension method, that great!

Answer (score 0):

I used Darin's answer. However, when it came to `data_my_custom_attribute`, they were not rendered as `data-my-custom-attribute`. So I changed Darin's code to handle this.

```
public static RouteValueDictionary DisabledIf(
    this object htmlAttributes,
    bool disabled
    )
{
    RouteValueDictionary htmlAttributesDictionary
         = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

    if (disabled)
    {
        htmlAttributesDictionary["disabled"] = "disabled";
    }
    return new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributesDictionary);
}
```