# Asp.Net MVC- Html.TextBoxFor - Set Autofocus property to false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have two input fields on my razor view. One for username and one for password.

If the username has a value passed in through the ViewBag then I don't want to set focus to the username field but rather have focus in the password field. But what happens at the moment is that the first Username input always receives the focus. The "false" value doesn't seem to do anything. I've had a google around and checked some other Stack Overflow posts but i still can't seem to find an answer on this.

I have simple code like so on my view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @placeholder = "Username", autofocus = (ViewBag.Username == "" ? "autofocus" : "false"), value = ViewBag.Username })

@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @placeholder = "Password", autofocus = (ViewBag.Username == "" ? "false" : "autofocus") })
```

I know i could just use JQuery to set the focus conditionally but i was hoping there would be a way through the Text Box Html Helper?

Comment: `autofocus` or `autofocus="autofocus"` or `autofocus="anythingAtAll"` all do exactly the same thing - they set the attribute.

Comment: So is there no way to not set the attribute?

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, Model.Username == "" ? (object)new { @placeholder = "Username", autofocus = "autofocus" } : (object)new { @placeholder = "Username" })` and similar for the second textbox (in reverse).

Comment: but note that you should never set the `value` attribute. And why do you have a model property named `UserName` and then add another `UserName` property in `ViewBag`? (that makes no sense at all - use the value of your model property)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke Very valid points. I've made those changes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autofocus is a boolean attribute. As per the [spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes), if it exists, it should be listed as either `autofocus="autofocus"` or simply `autofocus`. To "turn it off" it is a case of not adding it as an attribute on the input.

Following the advice in the excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8432183/3130094), there are a few ways to do what you want. One way is to create an extension method, and you could do it like this:

Create an extension method like so:

```
public static class AttributesExtensions
{
    public static RouteValueDictionary AutofocusIf(
        this object htmlAttributes, 
        bool autofocus
    )
    {
        var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        if (autofocus)
        {
            attributes["autofocus"] = "autofocus";
        }
        return attributes;
    }
}
```

Now, when you create your username textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @placeholder = "Username", value = (string) ViewBag.Username }.AutofocusIf(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string) ViewBag.Username)))
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie. This works great, however i did have to cast my ViewBag properties to actual types for the extension method to work. I updated your answer to include that.

Comment: @davey1990 - thanks for the edits. Glad you got it working :-)